# Which one is the right word in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, mathematics

One of my math teachers wrote this as part of the statement of a problem:

> ...This basis determines a topology which becomes the map *f* into a homeomorphism

This doesn't sound right to me (both me and my teacher are Spanish), but I'm not sure what the proper verb should be. Instead of *becomes*, should I write *makes*? Or *transforms*?

Comment: THis seems OK. I would place commas thus: the  map, f,into

Comment: That's really not enough context to tell how it should be worded.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you are completely sure of several largely unrelated things and either way what exactly do you not welcome about *This… determines a topology which becomes the  map f into…* please?

If in Spanish maths - which I suggest is as different from ordinary Spanish as English maths is from ordinary English - the answer is obvious; if in Spanish maths there is clearly something wrong with *This basis determines a topology which becomes the map f into a homeomorphism* then changes might well be needed.

*Becomes* and *transforms* are not interchangeable with *makes*.

*Becomes* speaks of a thing changing its outward characteristics but remaining intrinsically the same thing: the coward becomes a hero; the liability, an asset; that which we wanted, what we now have.

*Makes* speaks of that which creates a new thing, prolly itself remaining unchanged: the battle made the coward into a hero; changing fortune made a liability into an asset; a great deal of effort made what we wanted into that which now have.

*Transforms* speaks of changes but only in restricted circumstances. Coal and iron can transform each other into steel but to what extent does that *make* steel? If lead is *transformed* into gold by the Philosophers’ Stone how is that the same as lead *becoming* or being *made into* gold?

(Hint to most of you: that’s purely grammatical; we are not here looking at philosophy, physics or metaphysics.)